Generalization of Clebsch-Gordan coefficients for O(d)
How can one generalize the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients in O(d).
Clebsch-Gordan coefficients described here, for example, are for O(3), as far as I understand, but what if I am working in $S^d$ using the d-dimensional Spherical harmonics? How can I generalize them?

This is an old attempt of mine to understand exactly that. There are several links. Hope this helps
